# WordPress allow direct access to uploads/subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Im using Contact Form 7 plugin in order to upload files to my server (images,pdf's..)
The plugin creates a folder inside wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads , there i have all my uploaded files. My problem is that i cant direct access them from my browser like:
mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/myImage.jpg .
It seems that is an .htaccess problem,
tryed to put a .htaccess file in the wpcf7_uploads folder whith this:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

but no luck.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 only temporarily stores files and removes them once they have been e-mailed to the recipient(s).

You will need to hook into a CF7 action and handle the this process in a different way to store it on the server.

Try this link

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-leave-file-upload-on-server

Comment: thanx for the answer.ive already done that and i can see my files at the server

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file?

Comment: no in the htaccess inside the wpcf7_uploads folder i have only what u wrote in my answer